# jQuery form not submitting when no errors exist

Tags: jquery, validation, form-submit

I have an html form and some jQuery that validates the form. If all of the validations pass I would like to submit the form. When I press submit, the errors messages are appearing (if there are errors), however, when there are no error messages, the submit button kind of stalls and I get an error

> Unresponsive script error

I get the same results in both firefox and safari.

jQuery (the errors div is where all of the errors appear):

```
$("#joinForm").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!$(':text').val() || !$(':password').val()){

            $('#fillIn').remove();
            $('#errors').append("<p id='fillIn'>Please fill in all fields</p>");
        }
        else {
            $('#fillIn').remove();
        }


        if ($('#email').val()!= $('#reemail').val()){
            $('#noMatch').remove();
            $('#errors').append("<p id='noMatch'>Emails do not match</p>");
        }
        else{
            $('#noMatch').remove();
        }


        if ($('#email').val() == $('#reemail').val() && $(':text').val() && $(':password').val()){
            $('#joinForm').submit();
        }
        else{
            $('#errorModal').modal('show');
        }

    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<form method='POST' action='join_action.php' id='joinForm'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Full Name: </td><td><input type='text' name='name'></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email: </td><td><input type='text' name='email' id='email'></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Re-type Email: </td><td><input type='text' name='reemail' id='reemail'></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>New Password: </td><td><input type='password' name='password'></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='submit' value='Sign Up' name='signup' id='signup'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: It would be simplier to use `$('#signup').on('click'.....` and then call that submit on form

Comment: @arma but if the user has JS turned off i need the form to still submit

Comment: Well if no javascript it will still run native submit since you have that in your form. If you want your current example to work move `e.preventDefault();` to the end. After that modal call.

Comment: check my answer.. it may give you a clear view...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `e.preventDefault();` prevents the form from submission, and then you called `submit()` manually, this will fire another `submit` event, thus you got an infinite loop.

To fix it, call `preventDefault` only when the form is invalid.

```
$("#joinForm").on("submit", function (e) {
        var isValid = true;

        if (!$(':text').val() || !$(':password').val()){
            isValid = false;
            $('#fillIn').remove();
            $('#errors').append("<p id='fillIn'>Please fill in all fields</p>");
        }
        else {
            $('#fillIn').remove();
        }


        if ($('#email').val()!= $('#reemail').val()){
            isValid = false;
            $('#noMatch').remove();
            $('#errors').append("<p id='noMatch'>Emails do not match</p>");
        }
        else{
            $('#noMatch').remove();
        }


        if (isValid && $('#email').val() == $('#reemail').val() && $(':text').val() && $(':password').val()){
           // pass
        }
        else{
            $('#errorModal').modal('show');
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: thanks. how do i fix this?  i need preventDefault to stop form submission immediatly

Comment: where exactly should i place preventDefault?

Comment: i am still unsure where it goes. after the else statment? after the 2nd to last `});`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6437/discussion-between-qiao-and-user802370)

Answer (score 1):

Switch your last if statement to this:

```
    if (!($('#email').val() == $('#reemail').val() && $(':text').val() && $(':password').val())){
        $('#errorModal').modal('show');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Also remove the `e.preventDefault()` from the top of your code.

This just changes the logic to say "If we have errors, show the modal and stop the submit. Otherwise, carry on submitting"

Comment: how will this work?  the modal shows when there are errors. this if statement makes sure there are no errors

Comment: I wrapped your whole if statement in a !() to just give the opposite of whatever you were originally looking for. If it's not working, you'll need to modify the if statement to be whatever means "there are errors"

Answer (score 1):

you should use `e.preventDefault();` only when there is an error. the esiest way to do is, declare a flag and set it to true when there is an error and do something like ,

```
$("#joinForm").on("submit", function (e) { 
   var isError = false; // set the flag to false initially 

 // do whatever you want.

  if(error conditions)
   isError = true;  /// do this wherever you are expecting error

  // do something else        

  if(isError)  
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
$('#joinForm').submit(function(){

    if (!$(':text').val() || !$(':password').val()){

        $('#fillIn').remove();
        $('#errors').append("<p id='fillIn'>Please fill in all fields</p>");
    }
    else {
        $('#fillIn').remove();
    }


    if ($('#email').val()!= $('#reemail').val()){
        $('#noMatch').remove();
        $('#errors').append("<p id='noMatch'>Emails do not match</p>");
    }
    else{
        $('#noMatch').remove();
    }


    if ($('#email').val() == $('#reemail').val() && $(':text').val() && $(':password').val()){
        $('#joinForm').submit();
    }
    else{
        $('#errorModal').modal('show');
    }

    return false;
});
```

**SEE in the end:**

> return false;

Bye!

Answer (score 0):

Working code on 1.7.1 jQuery:

```
    $(function() {
        $("#joinForm").on("submit", function () {
            var validForm = true;
            if (!$(':text').val() || !$(':password').val()){

                $('#fillIn').remove();
                $('#errors').append("<p id='fillIn'>Please fill in all fields</p>");
                validForm = false;
            }
            else {
                $('#fillIn').remove();
            }


            if ($('#email').val()!= $('#reemail').val()){
                $('#noMatch').remove();
                $('#errors').append("<p id='noMatch'>Emails do not match</p>");
                validForm = false;
            }
            else{
                $('#noMatch').remove();
            }


            if (validForm){
                $(this).submit();
            }
            else{
                $('#errorModal').modal('show');
            }
        return false; 
    });
  });
```

Comment: What version of jquery you are using? it works for me on 1.7.1

Comment: i still got the error.  im using 1.7.1 as well.  maybe there is another problem with my code?

Comment: If you look in jsfiddle example i posted there's all your code and it's working, with minor tweak.